# NSDictionary into 1 NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

Is it possible to take 2 NSDictionaries and populate 1 NSMutableArray?
So lets say I have this situation:

dict1 = key/value of: 
id/firstname

dict2 = key/value of:
id/lastname

(These are populated from a database query to the server)

Now, I want to combine the dictionaries into an NSMutableArray of "user" objects. the user object has these variables, mapping to the 2 NSDict objects above. So:
id, firstname, lastname (everything is an NSString)

I tried various things.

The problem is the following, when I extract the NSDictionary key/values (using NSEnumerator - but also tried with a slower for loop) and add the resulting object into the mutablearray, the values of the objects inside the array get initialized to the **same** object for all preceeding values. Example:

id:1 - firstname: John - lastname: Brown
id:2 - firstname: Mike - lastname: Blue
id:3 - firstname: Mary - lastname: White

By the time I am done with the enumeration, and reach the end of the loop, my array looks like this (all objects are identical)

id:3 - firstname: Mary - lastname: White
id:3 - firstname: Mary - lastname: White
id:3 - firstname: Mary - lastname: White

Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what your issue is, a code snippet might help, but here's how I would go about it:

```
for (NSString *key in [dict1 allKeys]) {
  User *u = [[User alloc] initWithId:key
                           firstName:[dict1 objectForKey:key]
                            lastName:[dict2 objectForKey:key]];
  [users addObject:u];
  [u release];
}
```

I wouldn't use the `NSEnumerator` for the objects themselves because they are in no guaranteed order.

If that's already what you're doing, you may need to look at something wonky with your `User init` method.  Are you, in fact, using the same object over and over?

Comment: Thank you Ed - it worked like a charm! I was overcomplicating the situation by not leveraging my init method. Thanks again.